# Undo and Redo functionality in drawing application ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on a drawing app and I am able to draw with my finger touch. Now I am trying to implement clear, undo, and redo functionality.

In my view controller I have two IBAction methods for "clearAll" and "Undo". I have created a custom class called drawing.h and .m where I have written functions for handling touch events. Below are my functions.

The problem is undo and redo work but the last color select in all line in drawn in undo and redo.

[image: drowing in line view]

[image: after undo screensort]

Comment: so you can undo to remove lines but you also want to be able to undo a change of the drawing colour?

Comment: I Have Drowing In Five Lines And Different Color Last Line Drowing Red Color Then i Have Click  on Undo Then All Four line Are Red Color

Comment: so you're storing the line history and the current colour only? Not the line and associated colour? You need to show some code and data model details.

Comment: No I have a Create a Four Line First Red Second Green  Third Blue fourth Black and then Click Undo Then List Fourth line remove And remaining three line are as it no change in color and line but my problem  in i have click undo then remove last line remain three line are black color

Comment: Please Answer Me Fast .

Comment: NSDictionary *lineInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:rawImage, @"IMAGE",nil];
    [pointsArray addObject:lineInfo];
    UIBezierPath *_path=[pointsArray lastObject];
    [_stack addObject:_path];
    [pointsArray removeLastObject];
    [self.tempimage setNeedsDisplay];

Answer (score 1):

```
I Have Mistake In Touch End Method In Array Last Array Not Remove on last object 

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.tempimage.bounds.size);
        [self.tempimage.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
  rawImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   [self.tempimage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, tempimage.frame.size.width, tempimage.frame.size.height) blendMode:blendmode alpha:opacity];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
#if PUSHTOFILE
   lineIndex++;
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(writeFilesBG)
                           withObject:nil];
#else
    NSDictionary *lineInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:rawImage, @"IMAGE",nil];
    [pointsArray addObject:lineInfo];
    UIBezierPath *_path=[pointsArray lastObject];
    [_stack addObject:_path];
    [pointsArray removeLastObject];
    [self.tempimage setNeedsDisplay];
#endif
}
```